# Multi-line graphs in d3 with monthly weather data over several years, time-based x-axis problems

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I have data that's formatted as such:

`DATE,TAVG
1939-09,80.0
1939-10,60.0`

And so on, until 2018-12. I have used d3's .nest() function on this to separate it by years. Doing so allows me to plot a line for each year.

However, I'm getting tripped up by scales. The code sample `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.date.getMonth());}));` seems to return an array ["Dec", "Dec"], leaving all of my x-axis ticks as "Dec".

So, what exactly am I doing wrong here? How can I get my x-axis ticks to be "Jan", "Feb", etc.?

An image of the error being produced:

[D3 x-axis error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl4W3.png)

My code and the weather data I'm using is available on [this github repo](https://github.com/markblack96/d3-weather-data-charts).

The javascript code itself I'll reproduce here:

```js
// Define margins
var margins = {
    top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50
}, width = 600 - margins.left - margins.right,
   height = 270 - margins.top - margins.bottom;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");

// Scales for axes
var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width])//.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
            
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Line function
var weather_line = d3.line()
                        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date.getMonth());})
                        .y(function(d) { return y(d.tavg);});

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([1939, 2018]).range(["orange", "red"]);

// Svg object
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margins.left + margins.right)
            .attr("height", height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");
            
            
// Get data
// debuging variable
var debug;
var debug2;
var parseMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");
d3.csv("weather_data.csv",
    function(d) {
        return {
            date : parseTime(d.DATE),
            tavg : +d.TAVG
        };
    }).then(function(data){
        
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.date.getMonth());}));
        
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.tavg; })]);
        
        var years = d3.nest()
                      .key(function(d) { return d.date.getFullYear(); })
                      .entries(data);
        
        
        
        years.forEach(function(d, i) {
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", weather_line(d.values))
                .style("stroke", function() {return color(parseInt(d.key));});
        });
        
        // Add our axes
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+height+")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(12).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")));
            
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(4));
        
    });
```

Comment: month names are not really alphabetical. just set the domain as `[0, 11]`

Comment: Doing this worked, along with using a months array to format the ticks with `d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d => months[d])` in my call statement for the x-axis. Feels kind of hacky to use a months array, though. Is that something I should avoid doing?

Comment: create a dummy date for some year for the correct month and format this date to only give the 3-letter month name.